# Installing iOS 8.0 in Xcode 6.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios8.1, xcode6.1

After I upgraded the Xcode 6 to Xcode 6.1 I lost the simulators running iOS 8.0. 
Do you know a way to have them back?
I tried to create a new simulator, but it doesn't work.
[image: create new ios simulator]

Comment: Check this [Adding Older Simulators to XCode](http://subsymbolic.net/2012/10/15/adding-older-simulators-to-xcode/). using same method you can add older iOS 8 simulators to new Xcode.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying that solution.

Comment: This directly involves tools used primarily for programming. To me, this seems on-topic for SO.

Comment: Ditto.. it's about Xcode which is a development tool, so it's very much on topic.

Comment: In Xcode 6.1 you can add simulators manually. To do so go to Window -> Devices and press the + symbol left at the bottom.
Add a new simulator
Then you can choose a combination of device type and iOS version to create.

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491922/how-to-install-ios-7-0-and-ios-8-0-simulators-in-xcode-6-1 - you can either (a) install xcode 6.0 and use that, or (b) copy the simulators from xcode 6.0 and use them