# How to install iOS 7.0 and iOS 8.0 Simulators in Xcode 6.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6

I want to test my app on both iOS 7.0 and iOS 8.0. I upgraded my iPhone5 to iOS 8.1. Now the only way to test my app in these OS' are using Simulator. But after upgrading my Xcode to 6.1. I'm unable to see iOS 7.0 and 8.0 Simulators. I need to install these simulators in Xcode 6.1. Is there any way to install these Simulators in Xcode 6.1?

NOTE:

1) I copy pasted these simulator SDKs from old Xcode to the Xcode 6.1's contents but it didn't work.

2) I tried installing these from Xcode > Preferences > Downloads but these doesn't show up in the list.

3) I removed all the Devices from Xcode's Window > Devices and then restarted the Xcode and re-added them but these simulators doesn't show up.

Comment: Add them in the Devices window in Xcode. See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26508245/3302591

Comment: Try using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052c). I had an option to download iOS 7.0 Simulator.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Only iOS 7.0 and later simulators are supported on Xcode 6.0.x and 6.1.x.  Only iOS 7.1 and later simulators are supported on Xcode 6.2 and greater.

The older simulators runtimes are not compatible with the new CoreSimulator architecture.  You need to install Xcode 5.1.x if you want to run iOS 6.x simulators.

The iOS 7.0 simulator does not work on OSX Yosemite, so you need to be on OS X Mavericks if you want to run the iOS 7.0 simulator.

The iOS 8.0 simulator is not available as DLC.  It is only supported in Xcode 6.0.  If you really want to use it with newer versions of Xcode, you can try copying the iPhoenSimulator8.0.sdk and iOS 8.0.simruntime from Xcode 6.0 into Xcode 6.1, but as stated, this is not supported.

See:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.0.simruntime

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk

Comment: The question is not asking about running iOS 6.x.

Comment: @jeremy I'm finding the situation you describe is true for me.  I cannot get the 7.0 and 8.0 simulators installed in 6.1.1 on my Mavericks.

Can you cite any sources as to why 8.0 was dropped?  It seems like a confusing move on Apple's part.  I've found a number of posts like this where people are searching for their lost simulators. I'd have thought 8.0 was still worth testing against.

Maybe Apple thinks it's worthwhile to only target the latest versions (7.latest, 8.latest) and anything older is not worth the effort, but that's just a guess.

Comment: There were multiple reasons why we did not continue support for the iOS 8.0 simulator, but I will not further comment on specifics.  For historical context, I point out that we dropped support for the iOS 7.0 simulator soon after release and replaced it with the 7.0.3 simulator, so this is nothing new except for the fact that it was done with a minor version number rather than a tiny version number.

Comment: I lost my iPhone 7 simulators when upgrading Xcode to version 6.1.1. I think this is the problem. So I don't know how I can see how my app will work on iOS 7!

Comment: @new2ios What is unclear in the answer?  You just need to install the old iOS Simulators from XCode's Preferences.

Comment: Sorry, @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia, my mistake. I don't understand that I have to reinstall iOS 7 (7.1) simulator after updating (or may be upgrading) from Xcode 6.1 to Xcode 6.1.1. I already have them on Xcode 6.1, but obviously the nature of update requires to reinstall it. 10x a lot for remark!

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunate that Xcode 6.1.x and earlier delete your DLC on an upgrade.  This is because the content is itself installed inside of the Xcode.app bundle.  As of some changes to the Mac App Store last year, this extra content causes the entire app's signature to change which forces a complete re-download of the entire app (rather than a delta update) on upgrade, and that results in your old install vanishing.  Hopefully your download is still in Xcode's cache, so you hopefully just need to install it and not re-download it.

Comment: I've Xcode 6.1 on Yosemite and I've iOS 8.1 and iOS 7.1 Simulators on my Xcode, and both work fine! You can also install iOS SDK 7.1 on it too.

Comment: The question is asking about iOS 7.0 NOT 7.1! I do not understand why all answers addresses iOS 7.1 (which is easy to install). I have and app which crashes for a user in iOS 7.0 only (not iOS 7.1) and I can not find a way to reproduce nor test it (all of my devices are > 7.1).

Comment: @Lukasz You seem to have skipped over the relevant parts of the answer.  Had you noticed the second paragraph, you would see that 7.0 won't run on Yosemite.  If you need 7.0, use Mavericks.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia You are right. I was somehow referring to the comments.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I use Mavericks and still do not have an option in Xcode 6 to install iOS 7.0, but iOS 7.1 only. What am I missing?

Comment: @Lukasz Xcode 6.2 dropped support for iOS 7.0 simulators (even on Mavericks), so you need Xcode 6.1 or earlier on Mavericks for iOS 7.0 simulators

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you write that _"iOS 8.0 simulator is not supported any more as of the release of Xcode 6.1"_, when you said in the first paragraph that _"iOS 7.0 and later simulators are supported on Xcode 6.0.x and 6.1.x"_. Obviously iOS 8.0 is later that iOS 7.0, so one of the statements must be wrong, or what am I missing?

Comment: @GOTO0 Edited to hopefully make it clearer.  iOS 8.0 is only supported in Xcode 6.0.