# Xcode 6.3: 8.0 or 8.0.2 simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, sprite-kit

Problem:

- Xcode 6.3 doesn't have 8.0 simulators;
- I'm using swift 1.2 so i can't compile the project under earlier versions of Xcode;
- i have a lot of crashes of sprite kit on iOS 8.0 devices (crash reports not very helpful, them related to the sprite kit itself);
- it works well on iOS 7.1 and 8.1+

Is there a way to install build on 8.0 or 8.0.2 simulator from Xcode 6.3?

Example of crash report:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  SpriteKit                      0x0000000188ee72c8 SKCSprite::update(double) + 404
1  SpriteKit                      0x0000000188ee72d4 SKCSprite::update(double) + 416
2  SpriteKit                      0x0000000188ee72d4 SKCSprite::update(double) + 416
3  SpriteKit                      0x0000000188e9fb10 -[SKScene _update:] + 140
4  SpriteKit                      0x0000000188eba110 -[SKView(Private) _update:] + 568
5  SpriteKit                      0x0000000188eb7728 -[SKView renderCallback:] + 764
6  SpriteKit                      0x0000000188eb4794 __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 60
7  SpriteKit                      0x0000000188ee1724 -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 272
8  QuartzCore                     0x00000001889e964c CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 32
9  QuartzCore                     0x00000001889e94e4 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 324
10 IOKit                          0x0000000185a05d84 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 376
11 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184864f34 __CFMachPortPerform + 180
12 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184879b38 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
13 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184879a98 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
14 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184877a18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1640
15 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001847a5664 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
16 GraphicsServices               0x000000018d8e75a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
17 UIKit                          0x00000001890aa4f8 UIApplicationMain + 1488
18 Hedgehog                       0x000000010012fd3c main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000195516a08 start + 4
```

Comment: Try setting an "All Exceptions" breakpoint. This should tell you where in your code the error occurs.

Comment: This error reproducible only on iOS 8.0 and iOS 8.0.2, i don't have real devices with these os version and can't install on these simulators from xCode 6.3...

Comment: What real user would have 8.0 installed and not update to 8.1 or 8.2 or 8.3? You should not feel responsible for such people. Updates are how Apple fixes Cocoa bugs; it isn't your job to work around those bugs if they are fixed in later updates.

Comment: @matt That's quite a narrow point of view. There are many users that do not upgrade, instead remaining with what they had when they got with their phones. With the shiny new iPhone 6 devices, we'll have plenty of 8.0 users for a while.

Comment: @LeoNatan You're saying that if I buy an iPhone 6 today it ships with 8.0 on it? That's nuts. - What drives me insane is when Apple _introduces_ bugs in an update. iOS 8.3 has some Cocoa bugs that were fixed in iOS 8.1 and 8.2 and now have returned. You can't count on anything...

Comment: No not today, but a large part of the devices were sold after the announcement, and they came with 8.0.X. Then there was the wave of 8.1.X devices.

Comment: @matt Have you filed radars regarding the regressions you refer to in iOS 8.3?  Can you please provide me with the radar numbers?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia What would you do with them if you had them? You can't look things up in Apple's radar database. :(

Comment: @matt On the contrary, I can.  Please provide them, as I'd like to look into them, thanks.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia For example I just stumbled across this: 20562816 Negative kerning in an attributed string broke in iOS 7, was fixed in iOS 8, and was re-broken in iOS 8.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpted from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491922/how-to-install-ios-7-0-and-ios-8-0-simulators-in-xcode-6-1?rq=1):

> The iOS 8.0 simulator is not supported any more as of the release of Xcode 6.1. If you really want it, you can either install Xcode 6.0 or you can try copying the iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk and iOS 8.0.simruntime from Xcode 6.0 into Xcode 6.1, but as stated, this is not supported.
>
> See:
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.0.simruntime
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk

It relates to 6.1 but I think it is equally applicable to 6.3.