# Install simulator SDK 8.0 manually in Xcode7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, ios-simulator, xcode7

It is known that Xcode 7.0 does not support the iOS 8 simulator any more. So when I go to the download preferences I only find the iOS 8.1 simulator and higher. But I really need to test my code on iOS 8.0 and I don't have any device supporting that version, so I need to do this from the simulator.

I downloaded Xcode 6.0.1 (to extract the iOS 8.0 simulator) and installed it in my applications, but I could not run Xcode (since it cannot be run on El Capitan).

So what I tried to do is copy/paste the iOS 8.0 simulator:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk`

and

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.0.simruntime`

from Xcode 6.0.1 to Xcode 7.0 and **restarted the mac**

I then re-open Xcode 7.0, and go to Window -> Devices and enter the following:

[image]

I then hit "Create", but once created it shows up as iOS 9.0, and once I run the code on that simulator it reads the OS as 9.0 and not 8.0

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this please?

Comment: Why do you really need to test against the iOS 8.0 Simulator Runtime?  Why is testing against the iOS 8.1 Simulator Runtime insufficient?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia because the bug that is happening with the client is only on iOS 8.0

Comment: What's the issue? Given that you're just seeing it in iOS 8.0, it's quite possibly an OS bug.  Users should really upgrade to newer versions of iOS.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia the app is crashing randomly, only on iOS8.0

Comment: Provide a full crash log for help.  Have you tested with ASan?

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491922/how-to-install-ios-7-0-and-ios-8-0-simulators-in-xcode-6-1? Another way to try and track down is to integrate something like Crashlytics into your app and see what is reported when the user crashes. You should be doing this anyway and is a better solution that trying to install a particular simulator. Or you could use a cloud based service for testing that will provide the config you need such as https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/. Or google for others with this text "ios cloud services for testing".

Comment: @Grace: can't you simply run it using Xcode 6?

Comment: @xdeleon: we don't want to integrate any crahs log analytics in the app.

Comment: @Julian no I cannot run it on OS X El Capitan

Comment: @Grace; I have 6.0.1, which still runs on ElCap. I didn't have the time to verify that the 8.0 simulator works though...

Comment: @Julian, when I try to run it, it gives "You can’t use this version of the application with this version of OS X.", I'm on OS 10.11.1 and xcode 6.0.1, plus I need to test my code with the SDK 9 and not 8 since the build is based on the SDK 9

Comment: @Grace sorry, of corse I meant the latest, which is 6.4, if I'm right. I think it supports up to 8.1. If you really don't get it working, I suggest creating a 8.0 branch of your project and comment out anything only available since > 8.0. I don't see you cross-debugging 8.0 <> 9.1... :/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add an iOS 8 simulator, as an alternative, try to run this app on a device running iOS 8 with developer provision using xcode. This way it will also help to pick most of the LOCs where it is actually crashing. Also, for a random crash you might need to analyze app memory management using Instruments tool (but it also depends on crash reason).

Answer (score 0):

you can download it from xcode prefrences -> Downloads[image]

for manually you can get it from old xcode path(/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator) and paste it new xcode with same path.