# Xcode crash Logs not appearing

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store-connect, xcode7, crash-reports

I have an iOS app that is only crashing with the client on **iOS8.0**

At first I tried to install iOS simulator8.0 on my xcode7.0, OS X El Capitan to test the code but, facing some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955393/install-simulator-sdk-8-0-manually-in-xcode7-0), I dropped the case

Now, what I am trying to do is get the crash log from xcode's organizer, but weird things are happening:

- I am logged in xcode with my iTunes account
- The app had the checkbox on for "Include app symbols for your application…" when uploading it to testflight, BUT the build details in iTunes Connect shows "Includes Symbols: NO"
- The organizer does not show **every** versions of the app on iTunes Connect, although we can see all the versions and build numbers from my colleague's xcode.
- Organizer doesn't show all the crash log of the app of the given build number although I can see **some** crashes on different builds (On the other hand, my colleague can not see **any** crash log happening on the app for **the current version and for all the previous versions**)

Can anyone help me on any (or both) of the issues? Thanks

NB: I want to avoid to ask the client to send me his device's crash logs. Although one time I asked a client for the crash log from the device and there wasn't any crash registered on the device

Answer (score 2):

The reason you and your colleague do not see the same crash logs is likely
because your colleague is assigned a lesser role in your team.
(Say you are admin and he's technical)
Can't help with the Includes Symbols: NO issue cause I have
debug symbols stripping set to NO for both debug an release targets
and yet I see the exact same issue (Includes Symbols: NO in itc).
Apple just does not like to symbolicate I guess...