# app written in swift 2.1, xcode 7.2.1, uploaded to itunes with symbols but crash logs not available

Tags: swift2, ios9, testflight, crash-reports, xcode7.2

I have submitted an app to itunes for Beta Testing in TestFlight.

I followed the submission [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/UploadingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010547-CH2) and I submitted the app with Symbols.

One of the testers reported that the app is crashing.

In organiser, I can see all my build and the build associated with the issue.

However, wehn I select  the App Store --> build [id],  I get:

'`no crash information is available for this version`'

Any idea what might be going on?

Similar (but not identical as I am not getting any reports and am using different ios, xcode, swift) question with no responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157652/xcode-crash-logs-not-appearing).

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when a user says they've enabled '[share with developer](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202100)' when they did not...