# avoiding selector not found in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I downloaded a calendar tutorial and ran it with deployment target as iOS 6.1 and ran it in the simulator, everything went fine.  I loaded it onto a iOS 6.1 device and it crashed with "selector not found"

It uses 'startOfDayForDate'

```
return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] startOfDayForDate:self.start];
```

This crashes on the iOS 6.1 test device yet it works in the simulator even though I have a deployment target of iOS 6.1.

I used instancesRespondToSelector and found it doesn't respond.
I listed out the methods and found about 30 methods fewer when I run the same program on the device when compared to the simulator.

Note that the other settings are the same.

Q. How do you set the simulator to simulate a certain OS?

Is there some hidden setting I don't see that would cause the simulator to load methods from a different version of iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/startOfDayForDate:) it looks like this method is only supported in iOS 8.0 and later which is why this crashes on your iOS 6.1 device.

You are probably running a simulator for a version of iOS later than 8.0.

If you're running xCode 6.0 or later the earliest simulator you can download is iOS 7. This is better described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491922/how-to-install-ios-7-0-and-ios-8-0-simulators-in-xcode-6-1)